# BGP peers established in SDN

Tags: sdn, ryu, bgp, quagga

I downloaded a routine from github about interconnection about traditional network with sdn. The program establishes ibpg peers. When I run the program, there is a problem occurred shown as follows. How can I deal with this trouble?

[image]

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Since the peer closed the connection, you should check the logs and/or debug on the other side of the connection. The log file will probably explain why it didn't like your connection attempt / why it refused you.

You tagged quagga, so I assume that at least one of the side is quagga. It should be simple enough to enable some debug on the quagga cli to see what's going on.

Additionally, BGP can send notifications, notifying the peer of an error. So the connecting side should be aware of the error. This implies that the connection (TCP) was established and that the first BGP exchanges (BGP OPEN MSG) happened.

Maybe start with a tcpdump -vvv -i  -s0 'host 10.10.10.1 and port 179'